# How to set Record Sets in Amazon Route 53 to work for both www prefix and non-www prefix domains tied to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'm currently trying to make record sets for a domain that is associated with an EC2 instance with an Elastic IP. I've followed Amazon's EC2 documentation, but trying to navigate to my domain doesn't seem to be working without the www prefix.

It works perfectly fine with the www prefix, since my A record points directly to the instance's Elastic IP. I've also tested trying to send emails to info@foo.com, which also works perfectly.

Here is how I currently have my record sets within Route 53 as well as the nslookup results of querying both domains.

I can't post the images, since I have less than 10 reputation, but I've linked them to the album below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYb6n.jpg

Are there changes that I need to make to my Route 53 record sets to get both domains to load the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a just plain `foo.com` record. Create a new `A` record and don't put anything in the subdomain box (where you put `www` for the record that does work). `www` and non-www are technically totally separate records, even if most URLs use them for the same thing.

Comment: Should I have this A record value as the Elastic IP, just like my A record with the www prefix?